# Can use v-bind in keyframe?

Tags: vue.js, animation, vuejs3, vue-component, css-animations

Why keyframes are not compiled correctly to v-bind in Vue3 doc: (https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html)
I obtain i strange compiled string like --e9eea4ec- and the value not translate from data to animation keyframe.

```
   .goCenterfromRight {
      animation: goCenterfromRight 1s ease-in-out backwards;
    }
    
   @keyframes goCenterfromRight {
      0% {
        translate: v-bind(myVar + 'vw' +' ' 0);
      }
    
      100% {
        translate: 0 0
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should concatenate the `0` correctly :

```css
     0% {
        translate: v-bind(myVar + 'vw' +' '+ 0);
      }
```

or just do

```css
     0% {
        translate: v-bind(myVar + 'vw 0');
      }
```

Comment: Sadly is still not working, it got compiled like this var(--7a7a37b1-orizontalOffsetvw\ 0), where is myVar declared in data :/.